# how can i always focus to page using capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am working on testing rspec and using capybara for interact with form.

I have a problem when i run my file spec if i not focus to page i couldn't submit the form and got the 400 error code so how can focus to page when fill_in text box or click button.

here is the error code

```
"status": 400,
"result": {
    "error": "Grabbing app data from app store failed. Please try again."
}
```

here is my code interact with form

```
    select_visible(@state, "form label[for='state']+div.field a.chosen-single")
  select_visible(@platform, "form label[for='platform']+div.field a.chosen-single")
  if @appstore_search != nil && @appstore_search != ""
    page.find("#autocomplete_chosen a").click
    page.find("#autocomplete_chosen div.chosen-drop div.chosen-search input[type='text']").set(@appstore_search)
    if page.has_css?("#autocomplete_chosen ul.chosen-results li.active-result")
      page.find("#autocomplete_chosen ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(3)").click
    else
      fill_in('name', :with => @appstore_search)
    end
  else
    fill_in('name', :with => @name)
  end

  click_button 'Save'

  if page.find("form label[for='platform']+div")[:class].include?("field invalid")
    @warning_platform = page.find("form label[for='platform']+div.field.invalid aside.error-message").text
    puts @warning_platform
  end

  if page.find("form label[for='name']+div")[:class].include?("field invalid")
    @warning_name = page.find("form label[for='name']+div.field.invalid aside.error-message").text
    puts @warning_name
  end

  if page.has_css?('#alerts ul li')
    @message = page.find("#alerts ul li").text
    puts @message
  end
```

Please help me fix this problem or suggest me other solution.

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Comment: when clicked button the page is down

Comment: what do you mean by focus? i can't find any focus in your code?!

Comment: I don't know how to auto focus my page. I want you suggest me how to focus my page